# Error when pickling ParseResult in Python 3.5.1

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have test code that works in Python 2.7.11, but fails in Python 3.5.1:

```
import pyparsing as pp
import pickle

class Greeting():
    def __init__(self, toks):
        self.salutation = toks[0]
        self.greetee = toks[1]

word = pp.Word(pp.alphas+"'.")
salutation = pp.OneOrMore(word)
comma = pp.Literal(",")
greetee = pp.OneOrMore(word)
endpunc = pp.oneOf("! ?")
greeting = salutation + pp.Suppress(comma) + greetee + pp.Suppress(endpunc)
greeting.setParseAction(Greeting)

string = 'Good morning, Miss Crabtree!'

g = greeting.parseString(string)

pkl = 'test .pkl'
pickle.dump(g, open(pkl, 'wb'))
pickle.load(open(pkl, 'rb'))
```

The error message is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Arne/parser/test.py", line 23, in <module>
   pickle.load(open(pkl, 'rb'))
TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'toklist'
```

`__new__()` refers to `pyparsing.ParseResults.__new__(cls, toklist, name=None, asList=True, modal=True )`.

Is it still in general possible to pickle objects returned by `pyparsing` in Python 3.5.1 or has something changed?

Could somebody provide a brief code sample of their use of `pickle` and `pyparsing 2.0.7`?

My real grammar takes a few minutes to parse, so I really would appreciate being able to store the results before further processing.

Comment: Please show (a) the full error message (including the full stack trace), and (b) a working example that produces this error.

Comment: @poke - I changed my code sample as you suggested. The stack trace is only that short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fails with `protocol=2` (optional 3rd arg to `pickle.dump`), but passes if you use pickle `protocol` = 0 or 1.  On Python 2.7.10, 0 is the default protocol. On Python 3.5, pickle has protocols 0-4, and again, pickling ParseResults only works with protocols 0 and 1. But in Py3.5, the default protocol has changed to 3.  You can work around this problem for now by specifying a protocol of 0 or 1.

More info on pickle protocols at https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle#data-stream-format

Comment: The next release of pyparsing will support all pickle protocols 0-4.

Comment: By the way, pyparsing is awesome!